# Ask the server if I am logged in

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a function that tells me whether a user is logged in or not.

I have a service called `AuthenticationService`, and in this, the function `isLoggedIn()`.

```
this.isLoggedIn = function() {

    return $http.get($rootScope.api + '/auth/is-logged-in');

};
```

However, for this to work, I have to make the caller check the result, instead of just getting `true`/`false`.

```
App.controller('Controller', ['AuthenticationService', function(AuthenticationService) {

    AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn().then(function() {
        console.log('You are logged in');
    }, function() {
        console.log('You are not logged in. Lets redirect you');
    })

}]);
```

I certainly would like to avoid having that piece of code in every controller that needs to know if a given user is logged in.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Usually, the app assumes that it stays logged in after checking it once. If the session expires, you can reset that status in the error handling (every request will presumably fail with 400 Forbidden if that happens).

Comment: @Thilo Don't you mean 403 Forbidden?

Comment: Yes, 403 Forbidden. But what actually happens depends on your server-side stack and how nice it plays with API requests. Point is, you should be able to determine from the error response that the session is invalid now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it on run method of application and check at routeChangestart event :-

```
  app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService', function ($rootScope, $location, AuthenticationService) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {

            if (!AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
                console.log('DENY');
                event.preventDefault();
                $location.path('/login');
            }
            else {
                console.log('ALLOW');
                $location.path('/home');
            }
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: Did you actually try this? With `AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()` returning af promise, I doubt that will work

Comment: Hey this is just a prototype you have to implement it properly according to your requirement.Obviously this will not work because it will return promise .You have to implement the same logic as you used in your controller.